# Remap context menu call on qwidget

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qwidget

I have my custom widget inherited from QWidget, and I've connected the widget's menu-calling signal to my slot.

```
connect(m_ontologyView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), SLOT(showContextMenuSlot(QPoint)));
```

Now I want user to be able to change button calling the context menu. Normally it's called with right mouse button, but how do I tell the widget to call the menu with a button of my choice?

I'm on Qt 5.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `QWidget::customContextMenuRequested`, you will need to reimplement the widgets mouse event functions, `QWidget::mousePressEvent,  QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent and QWidget::mouseMoveEvent`. Inside of these events, you can then show you menu using `QMenu::popup`. (The point can be extracted from the mouse events).